# How do I know the Methods in AndroidJavaObject class in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've use this code

```
using (var activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        {
            using (var wifiManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "wifi"))
            {
                tempSSID = wifiManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getConnectionInfo").Call<string>("getSSID");
            }
        }
```

So how do I know the Methods like "getConnectionInfo","getSSID","getSystemService" because I want to scan SSID nearby and connect to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking into the [**Android API**](https://developer.android.com/reference)!

---

In the first line

```
var activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
```

you get the current [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)

Then in the second line you use [`getSystemService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String))

```
var wifiManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "wifi")
```

to get a reference to the [`WifiManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager) service.

Then in

```
wifiManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getConnectionInfo")
```

you are calling [`getConnectionInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConnectionInfo()) on it which returns a [`WifiInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html) on which you finally call [`getSSID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID())